# Don't know how to set a Boolean workitem field in Azure DevOps Server to display Yes/No instead of True/False

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, workitem

I'm running Azure DevOps Server 2019 and I added a Boolean field to my User Story work item. The description for Boolean fields says "Boolean: Adds a True/False or Yes/No field.". It defaults to displaying a True/False toggle. I can't find how to change it to display a Yes/No toggle instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for confusion. The value "Yes/No" is actually not supported for a Boolean field type by default. An a workaround, you can use `String` type instead of `Boolean` type, which render a dropdown box for `Yes/No`:

```
<FieldDefinition name="MyField" refname="My.Field" type="String">
  <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
    <LISTITEM value="Yes" />
    <LISTITEM value="No" />
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
</FieldDefinition>
```

Comment: I know that you can make a dropdown with Yes/No options, but users wanted a checkbox or toggle instead. So, there is no way to change the Toggle text to something other than True/Fales?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you set Yes/No to a Boolean type, you'll get error "Yes is an invalid value for field type Boolean".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In DevOps Server 2022 this still cannot be customized. It could be useful to have the option to set the label text in the UI to some other than "true/false". One can only hope for this feature to come in a later version.